# PLSQL: How can I prevent an error in a trigger from canceling the original operation?

Tags: plsql, error-handling, triggers

maybe you can help me with the following question:

I have a table table1. There is a trigger trigger1 on tabel1 that basically says: "After insert on table1, call procedure xyz".

Later on, the procedure xyz is changed again, which causes an error when it's called, which in turn prevents the trigger from acting and even stops the insert from happening.

I would like to ask if there is a way to design the trigger so that it does not block the insert, even if an error occurs during the triggers action?

Thank you!

Comment: Add an exception block in the Procedure ? that shouldn't be so difficult right!

Comment: If it doesn't matter whether procedure `xyz` succeeds or fails why bother calling it at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can add exception block and prevent errors see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm